# What does one use a saw for?

Tags: equipment

In [the 1939 illustrated book *Madeline*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeline_%28book_series%29) is a kitchen scene. On the counter are plates (or bowls), a colander, a ladle, a saucepan, a large knife — and [a hand saw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_saw). Is a hand saw a kitchen implement? If so, what's it for?

Comment: Does the handsaw look precisely like the sort of cross-cut handsaws that are in that picture? Butcher handsaws of the sort suggested in the answers here tend, as they say, to look more like hacksaws. Butchers generally called then *handsaws*, but if you'd known that already you wouldn't have been asking that question. It's a long time since I last read *Madeline* so I can't remember what any saws in it looked like.

Comment: @JonHanna, I don't recall what the saw in _Madeline_ looks like, but I recall that the blade is broad (rather than thin and held in place by a frame as is usual, I think, of hacksaws).

Answer (score 11):

Any Kitchen I worked in –that does a bit of butchering– has one (any butcher also). It's for sawing bones.

At the time you would not throw anything out of an animal, and a lot of people would make their stock or put a piece of bone in a stew or soup for taste. But, as far as I know, they usually look like a [hacksaw](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000DJYY2) not like a the one you're showing.

Maybe the illustrator did not know what a kitchen saw looked like. He's been asked to draw one and did a hand saw by mistake.

This type of saw could be also used in a pastry shop. At some stage (and still, apparently according to @divi) wedding and other momumental cakes, but also smaller ones, were consolidated with pieces of wood or other non comestible material.

Comment: It's also entirely possible that the illustrator thought a hand saw would be more recognizable to the reader, or that classic handsaws were more common in kitchen usage at the time.  Disposable blades for a hacksaw would have been harder to come by in the 1930s than they are today.

Comment: I wondered the same,so I checked Wikipedia: hacksaws were already in industrial production in their modern form in 1898. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacksaw

Comment: Yes, but apparently by a single producer; I think it's difficult to assume that would have been the standard in a majority of kitchens at the time, even though it may be the modern choice. Perhaps we can find photographic references instead.

Comment: Have a look at p 63 of this 1865 [book] (http://books.google.fr/books?id=ODBFAAAAcAAJ&dq=butcher%20saw&hl=fr&pg=PA62#v=twopage&q=saw&f=false) It's not butchery, but it's still for sawing bones...about 70 years before the book of OP.

Comment: I'm not sold on that, since it's a book on surgery and the author goes into great deal about the design, like he's trying to convince an unfamiliar reader.  This seems more convincing, it's supposedly from the 1930s and there are clearly some large hacksaws: http://www.ci.pinole.ca.us/about/images/history_butcher_lg.jpg but that's still from a professional butcher, not a domestic kitchen.

Comment: The illustrator most certainly did know what a kitchen saw was; Bemelmans, who both wrote and illustrated the Madeline books (though the later books in the series are by his grandson) was pretty well-known as a gourmet, and was a restaurateur at least once in his life.

Comment: Instrument styles change over time, it's not inconceivable that a regular handsaw would have been in use in the past. Given that for most people you'd simply clean up the saw used to cut kindling for the oven and then use it to cut the bones for the stock for your soup, you'd save yourself having to have 2 potentially expensive tools.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to cutting up bones, I've also found the hand saw handy when layering cakes. I've used it for cutting woden and plastic dowels to specific length for cake layering.

Answer (score 2):

It could conceivably be used for sawing through bones. Or perhaps in the book the saw has been left on the counter by somebody?

Comment: Of course in the book the saw may have been just left around. I was asking about saws in kitchen use, not why the saw is in the book: the book was just my motivation for asking. Anyway, thank you (for the bone answer). +1

Answer (score 1):

I've used a hand saw to cut up bones when making stock making a long leg of lamb fit a roasting pan, other than that I can't think of any use for them in the kitchen. Serrated knives are commonly used to cut bread, but they don't look like hand saws. There are also tomato knives that are serrated, however they would be hard to mistake for a hand saw as well.

It's possible that the illustrator just added some implements to fill the scene, I wouldn't take that book as a true source of what a 30s kitchen looked like.

Comment: It was illustrated by a restauranteur and gourmet, though, which would influence the composition's accuracy.